# Did Cambridge award LLB?

Tags: united-kingdom, terminology, law

Please see the titled question.  Like Oxford's, [Cambridge's undergraduate and first law degree](https://www.undergraduate.study.cam.ac.uk/courses/law)  is a BA, not LLB. But SCC Justice [Ian Binnie](https://litigate.com/IanBinnie) exhibits

> University of Cambridge (1962) LLB

[Andrew Lewis](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/laws/people/prof-andrew-lewis) and HK barrister [Cheng Huan](http://chenghuansc.com/cheng-huan/) do too.

> He holds an LL.B. degree from Trinity Hall, Cambridge where he also completed a thesis on the legal aspects of boundary disputes between China and the Soviet Union.

[image]

Is this a typo?

Comment: @Poidah How is a question about academic qualifications not relevant?

Comment: The question seemed to be focused on whether these people are seeking to misrepresent themselves. We would never know that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Cambridge LLB was a Master's level qualification, which was renamed to [LLM in the 1980s](https://www.mcl.law.cam.ac.uk/the-faculty-of-law) in order to avoid confusion with the more widely used meaning of LLB as an undergraduate degree.

Comment: To add to the confusion, the Cambridge MA is *not* an academic qualification at all - basically it confirms your voting rights in the university governance procedures, and has a few nice side effects like lifetime membership of the University Library. https://www.cambridgestudents.cam.ac.uk/your-course/graduation-and-what-next/cambridge-ma

Comment: To add to the confusion, before the renaming of the LlB in the 1980s, Cambridge also awarded a higher LlM master's degree in law. There are probably some old-style Cambridge LlMs still aroung.